# PHP's fopen/fread/fwrite equivalent in golang

Tags: go

Is there an equivalent Php's fopen/fread/fwrite method in golang?

At the moment, I currently move, write and append to []byte with an offset, then write all thru os.File.Write(). But I'm wondering if there's a method that I can do directly to and from a file.

Comment: I would suggest examining the documentation for `os.File`.

Comment: See also [io/ioutil](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fopen

os.OpenFile https://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile

> fread

No identical match, but similer (*os.File)Read https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Read

> fwrite

(*os.File)Write https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write